# Detect in javascript when an iframe has been completely loaded, upon an automated click event

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe

I’m trying to write a bookmarklet to automate actions on a webpage.

Here’s my current code:

```js
javascript: (() => {
  window.onload = (event) => {
    click_on_menu.click(); // This action shows the iframe
    let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_of_interest");
  }
})();
```

But the problem is the variable `iframe` is always `null`.

Here’s the full code:

```js
javascript: (() => {
  output_window = window.open("https://example.com");
  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
      if (mutation.type === "childList") {
        console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
      } else if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
        console.log("The " + mutation.attributeName + " attribute was modified.");
      }
    }
  };

  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  window.onload = (event) => {
    console.log("page is fully loaded");
    const observer_iframe_loaded = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer_iframe_loaded.observe(output_windows.document.body, config);
    click_on_menu.click();
  };
})();
```

Why is `iframe` always `null`?

Comment: Can you provide HTML so I can debug your code and see what the problem is?

Comment: I am afraid I can't do that.

Comment: The fact that the iframe variable is null when selecting it means that there is something going on with the HTML and we need to see it. Otherwise we cannot fix the problem for you.